# Decorator to call function for every element of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, polymorphism, python-decorators

Does one of the standard (or at least popular) libraries define a decorator which could be used on a function that receives a single element (like an integer) and does not return anything?
Then, calling function with a *single* element, would simply pass the data to it and in case an Iterable is used as an argument, the function would be called for every element of it.

I am familiar with the [Single-dispatch functions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0443/), but for such simple case, even using them just to recognise if an element is an Iterable and calling function in a loop for each of its elements seems like a worse (longer) boilerplate than simply implementing this behaviour directly into the target function.

Comment: did you try just writing one? seems pretty straightforward, although, I question the overall wisdom of doing this

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I could and will if no one will answer this question, but such polymorphism seems common and high-level enough, that I would be surprised if no solution was available in the standard library similar to itertools or functools. I tried searching for one, but found nothing. This question is my last resort.

Comment: such polymorphism is *not common* actually, and frankly, a bad practice IMO. Notable examples exist, however. But even in, say numpy, there is a ton of baggag related to how "scalars" behave implicitly like singleton vectors

Comment: And here is a question: how do you define a "single element"? Should `foo("bar")` treat the string as an iterable, as it is surely is iterable?

Comment: Isn't it better than implementing a function only for one of these cases and expecting users with the other data type to call it in a for loop / create single-element lists at every call depending on the approach? Or do you suggest some other solution? To be less vague, I'm implementing a wrapper for an API that expects a list, but I know that the input will often consist of a single element.

Comment: No, it is absolutely better for the caller to handle this, IMO. Perhaps, ask yourself, can you name a *function in the standard library that has this sort of interface?* Certainly, not in the built-in functions. Maybe somewhere in the standard lib, but it's certainly not common

Comment: like, does `map(f, xs)` say, when you provide `xs = 1`, "oh! you must mean `[1]`". No, it doesn't. It tells you "hey, I expected an iterable and you provided something that isn't iterable, here is an error and stack trace".

Comment: To answer your second question, for type X, the final decorated function would take: X | Iterable[X], so I don't think that the string in question would be a problem. Maybe I underestimate the range of Iterable, but it should be no less than a list (with "free" support for set and tuple as a bonus).

Comment: Strings **are iterable**. If you have a function that takes a string, but you want it to accept a list of strings, then you cannot rely on *being an iterable* to distinguish between a string or a list of strings. And a decorator can't know this and be *general*.

Comment: All right, I see the potential vagueness. I thought about the map as well, but figured that it does not disprove the validity of what I try to do, since 1. it's simpler 2. is expected to return a result, which my function will not. However, I'm not going to take a hard stance that what I try to do is a good practice. Your argument about a lack of such functions had to come from someone more experienced, as I could simply not know them. I think this might resolve this discussion. Thank you.

Comment: https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.always_iterable would make this easier to handle on the caller side.

Comment: @bbayles That's an interesting suggestion indeed, since it also handles string and bytes corner-cases (are they all?). It requires a new dependency, but it's something to think about once the number of such calls would become cumbersome.